# Android-Databinding TextField with Regex

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I'm using M3 TextField with XML data binding. I want to send input to ViewModel and if is valid, text field's text should equal to this input, else should no change on TextField's text.

Here is XML code:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:suffixText="..."
            app:suffixTextColor="?colorOutline">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
                android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.updateText(text)}"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is ViewModel:

```kotlin
private val _text = MutableStateFlow("")
val text: StateFlow<String> = _text.asStateFlow()

fun updateText(text: CharSequence) {
     val regex = "..." // -> A regex for validation
     val isValid = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text).find()
     if (isValid) _text.value = text.toString()
}
```

When I run this code, Text value in viewModel does not change when not valid to regex. However, the textfield's input changes even if it is not valid to regex.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your ViewModel code to store the previous valid input text and only update the text field's text if the new input is valid. Otherwise, restore the previous valid input text.

```
private val _text = MutableStateFlow("")
private var previousValidText = ""

val text: StateFlow<String> = _text.asStateFlow()

fun updateText(text: CharSequence) {
    val regex = "..." // A regex for validation
    val isValid = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text).find()
    if (isValid) {
        _text.value = text.toString()
        previousValidText = text.toString()
    } else {
        _text.value = previousValidText
    }
}
```

and In your XML code, update the android:onTextChanged attribute to use a lambda expression and call the updateText method with the new text value.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
    android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.updateText(text)}"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```